# Can berry bushes be moved in Valheim?

Tags: valheim

Berries are important for potions, like health and poison resistance. It's inefficient to roam around finding berry bushes and hoping that they've regrown. Is there a way to move the berry bushes, or to plant berry bushes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. You have to go from forest to forest and pick them. I believe they will respawn over time, so you can come back to them later at least.

Comment: Kinda lame, but also kinda what I figured. Thanks!

Comment: Marking forageable locations on your map with the amount and type when you find something like berries or mushrooms is a good way of cutting down on searching at later times. I don't know the exact amount of time that has to pass for them to replenish but I don't believe the time needed is more than 2-3days for most forageables.